# Why does `coalesce()` function return multiple values?

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

In the example data, I applied `coalesce()` on column `LAB1` for each ID group in r. I was expecting there is only one value returned for each group, however, it seems like `coalesce` returns the whole column. I wonder why the `coalesce()` does not work as expected, any suggestion is appreciated.

```
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 2),
                 LAB1 = c(NA, 2, 3, NA))
#   ID LAB1
# 1  A   NA
# 2  A    2
# 3  B    3
# 4  B   NA

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(LAB = coalesce(LAB1), .groups = "drop")
#   ID      LAB
# 1 A        NA
# 2 A         2
# 3 B         3
# 4 B        NA

## expected result
#   ID      LAB
# 1 A         2
# 2 B         3
```

This is a simplified example. I am sure there are more ways to achieve the desired output, I would like to understand why the `coalesce()` does not apply here, is that because it only applies on multiple columns in a data frame instead of a single vector? If `coalesce()` is an aggregate function like functions `min`, `max`, why others can return single value when used in the `summarize()`?

Comment: Are you using `coalesce` for `LAB1` and `LAB2` i.e. `coalesce(LAB1, LAB2)`.  May be based on your expected, you need `filter`, instead of `coalesce` i.e. `df %>% select(-LAB2) %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(!is.na(LAB1))`

Comment: The point of `coalesce` is to talk multiple columns that might have missing values, and go element-by-element to fill in the missing values with the first non-missing values. The length of values is maintained. You seem to want to `filter` out missing values, shortening the length/number of rows.

Comment: From your example, it's not clear that the grouping matters. Maybe something like `df %>% rename(LAB = LAB1) %>% filter(!is.na(LAB1))` This renames the renames the column and drops rows with `NA` values.

Comment: If the grouping *does* matter, you need to tell us how: do you want to keep the first non-NA row in each group, or the last, or the biggest, or something else? Regardless, we won't use `coalesce()` as that's not what `coalesce()` does. `coalesce()` only does something if you give it **multiple** columns. If you run the example code at the bottom of the `?coalesce` help page, it illustrates `coalesce` nicely.

Comment: Thanks @GregorThomas. I am confused by the use of coalesce, I don't understand if it's an aggregate function, why it does not behave like other aggregate functions like min, max that can return single value for each group when used in `summarize` function. Is that because it's only designed for multiple columns?

Comment: `coalesce` is not an aggregate function. I'm not sure why you think it is. Have you run the examples at the bottom of the `?coalesce` help page? If you do, please notice that they do not do any aggregation.